# Tibco JMS (EMS) TimeToLive per client?

Tags: java, tibco, tibco-ems, ems

I haven't been able to figure this one out from Google alone. I am connecting to a non-durable EMS topic, which publishes updates to a set of data. If I skip a few updates, it doesn't matter, as the following update will overwrite it anyway.

The number of messages being published on the EMS topic is quite high, and occasionally for whatever reason the consumer lags behind. Is there a way, on the client connection side, to determine a 'time to live' for messages? I know there is on other brokers, but specifically on Tibco I have been unable to figure out whether it's possible or not, only that this parameter can definitely be set on the server side for all clients (this is not an option for me).

I am creating my connection factory and then creating an Apache Camel jms endpoint with the following code:

```
    TibjmsConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new TibjmsConnectionFactory();
    connectionFactory.setServerUrl(properties.getProperty(endpoints.getServerUrl()));
    connectionFactory.setUserName(properties.getProperty(endpoints.getUsername()));
    connectionFactory.setUserPassword(properties.getProperty(endpoints.getPassword()));

    JmsComponent emsComponent = JmsComponent.jmsComponent(connectionFactory);
    emsComponent.setAsyncConsumer(true);
    emsComponent.setConcurrentConsumers(Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("jms.concurrent.consumers")));
    emsComponent.setDeliveryPersistent(false);
    emsComponent.setClientId("MyClient." + ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName() + "." + emsConnectionNumber.getAndIncrement());
    return emsComponent;
```

I am using tibjms-6.0.1, tibjmsufo-6.0.1, and various other tib***-6.0.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JMSExpiration property can be set **per message** or, more globally, **at the destination level** (in which case the JMSExpiration of all messages received in this destination is overridden). It cannot be set per consumer.

One option would be to create a bridge from the topic to a custom queue that only your consumer application will listen to, and set the "expiration" property of this queue to 0 (unlimited). All messages published on the topic will then be copied to this queue and won't ever expire, whatever their JMSExpiration value.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for lol - I like your 'custom queue with its own TTL' idea though, thanks!